# How to get next month Previous month in Bootstrap date picker instead of next previous icon?

Tags: javascript, html, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap [datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/) & I want to change display next month & previous month instead of arrows. I have done some functionality but is not working accurately...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
  }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    $('#dt_due').val(e.format('dd/mm/yyyy'));
  }).on('changeMonth', function(e) {
    var prevMonth = new Date(e.date).getMonth()-1;
    console.log(prevMonth);
    prevMonth > 12 ? prevMonth = 0 : prevMonth;
    var currMonth = new Date(e.date).getMonth();
    console.log(currMonth);
    $('.pickDate').find('table .prev').html(monthNames[prevMonth]);
    var nextMonth = new Date(e.date).getMonth() + 1;
    console.log(nextMonth);
    nextMonth > 12 ? nextMonth = 0 : nextMonth;
    $('.pickDate').find('table .next').html(monthNames[nextMonth]);
    $('#dt_due').val(e.format('dd/mm/yyyy'));
  });

  function getInitMonths() {
    var prevMonth = new Date().getMonth();
    console.log(prevMonth);
    var currMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    console.log(currMonth);
    console.log(monthNames[currMonth - 1])
    $('.pickDate').find('table .prev').html(monthNames[currMonth - 2]);
    var nextMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 2;
    console.log(nextMonth);
    nextMonth > 12 ? nextMonth = 0 : nextMonth;
    $('.pickDate').find('table .next').html(monthNames[nextMonth]);
  }
  getInitMonths();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<div id="datepicker" class="pickDate"></div>
```

How can I do that?

Note:- Issue comes when month is December, January...

Please Help/suggest to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var monthMinusOneName = moment().subtract(1, "month").startOf("month").format('MMMM');
  var monthPlusOneName = moment().add(1, "month").startOf("month").format('MMMM');
  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
  }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    $('#dt_due').val(e.format('dd/mm/yyyy'));
  }).on('changeMonth', function(e) {
    var monthMinusOneName = moment(e.date).subtract(1, "month").startOf("month").format('MMMM');
    var monthPlusOneName = moment(e.date).add(1, "month").startOf("month").format('MMMM');
    $('.pickDate').find('table .prev').html(monthMinusOneName);
    $('.pickDate').find('table .next').html(monthPlusOneName);
  });

  function onInit() {
    var monthMinusOneName = moment().subtract(1, "month").startOf("month").format('MMMM');
    var monthPlusOneName = moment().add(1, "month").startOf("month").format('MMMM');
    $('.pickDate').find('table .prev').html(monthMinusOneName);
    $('.pickDate').find('table .next').html(monthPlusOneName);
  }
  onInit()
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="datepicker" class="pickDate"></div>
```

Note:- I have added moment js for next month & previous month's name.

Answer (score 1):

> You need to define the implementation of `getInitMonths()` outside the
>   `document.ready`.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajay2345/6bhr92f4/11/) running without errors.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
  }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    $('#dt_due').val(e.format('dd/mm/yyyy'));
  }).on('changeMonth', function(e) {
    var prevMonth = new Date(e.date).getMonth()-1;
    console.log(prevMonth);
    prevMonth > 12 ? prevMonth = 0 : prevMonth;
    var currMonth = new Date(e.date).getMonth();
    console.log(currMonth);
    $('.pickDate').find('table .prev').html(monthNames[prevMonth]);
    var nextMonth = new Date(e.date).getMonth() + 1;
    console.log(nextMonth);
    nextMonth > 12 ? nextMonth = 0 : nextMonth;
    $('.pickDate').find('table .next').html(monthNames[nextMonth]);
    $('#dt_due').val(e.format('dd/mm/yyyy'));
  });

  function getInitMonths() {
    var prevMonth = new Date().getMonth();
    console.log(prevMonth);
    var currMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    console.log(currMonth);
    console.log(monthNames[currMonth - 1])
    $('.pickDate').find('table .prev').html(monthNames[currMonth - 2]);
    var nextMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 2;
    console.log(nextMonth);
    nextMonth > 12 ? nextMonth = 0 : nextMonth;
    $('.pickDate').find('table .next').html(monthNames[nextMonth]);
  }
  getInitMonths();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<div id="datepicker" class="pickDate"></div>
```

Comment: let me check please wait.

Comment: on change need to fix the proper month. I am also working on it

Comment: btw why you are doing this $('.pickDate').find('table .next').html(monthNames[nextMonth]);

Comment: actually I need to show next month and previous month instead of next and previous arrows

Comment: you saying you don't need arrows.? then whats the issue?

Comment: I need to show... Previous month instead of a previous arrow(<<) && Next month instead if next month(>>).

Comment: Done. check now.

Comment: Check now. please mark it as resolved. if you think it answered your question.  this will help others too.

Comment: Thanks for your time & efforts... I think your solution is good but not correct.
so I have given you +10...Look at mine answer I have used moment for calculation...
will solve the issue Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: i have solved it without adding library which was not included in your question. i was assuming that you dont want to add this library. otherwise i already knew this.

Comment: Click on next month name IF you solve that I will give accept the answer :-)

Comment: @ParthRaval brother it is working on next month as well. i informed you that i have updated the answer.